# How to avoid database connection while testing service layer in spring boot application with Junit5

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, junit5, hikaricp

I am trying to unit test a service method which internally calls a repository method. My Test method is as follows:-

```
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    private static Employee emp;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        emp = new Employee(99, "TestUser");
    }

    @Test
    public void listAllEmployeesTest() throws Exception {
        List<Employee> allEmployee = Arrays.asList(employee);
        Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(allEmployee);
        List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>) cashierService.listAllEmployee();
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(allEmployee,employeeList);
    }
}
```

What I am asking is not a issue actually. When I am running my above, Spring boot application starts up and trying to create hikari pool initialization using DB connection.

How can I avoid this as it's unit test and I am mocking the repository and not interacting with database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe u can try to load only the classes that u need to load by adding

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {EmployeeRepository.class,EmployeeService.class})
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually to test the service layer, it is not necessary to use Spring Test framework. You can mock all beans used by your service except if you really need Spring context.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    private static Employee emp;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        emp = new Employee(99, "TestUser");
    }

    @Test
    public void listAllEmployeesTest() throws Exception {
        List<Employee> allEmployee = Arrays.asList(employee);
        Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(allEmployee);
        List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>) cashierService.listAllEmployee();
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(allEmployee,employeeList);
    }

}
```